# DataGrid Combobox SelectionChanged Event firing on scroll

Tags: c#, mvvm, datagrid, prism, selectionchanged

I am having trouble with the `SelectionChanged` event trigger for a combobox on my data grid.

The *combobox items* source is bound to my view model. The *combobox selected item* is also bound to my view model.

When I change the combobox selected item, a delegate command on the view model is fired which goes off and updates etc. But when I scroll the data grid the `SelectionChanged` event also fires.

I am also using Prism MVVM.

Here is my **XAML**:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Selected Reason" Width="150">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Reasons, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReason}">
          <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
              <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ReasonChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
              </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ComboBox>
      </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Here is my **View Model** command:

```
private DelegateCommand<T> _reasonChangedCommand;
public DelegateCommand<T> ReasonChangedCommand =>
            _reasonChangedCommand ?? (_reasonChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<T>(ReasonChanged));

    private async void ReasonChanged(T obj)
    {
         if (obj != null)
         {       
             await _updateRepository.UpdateAsync(obj);          
         }
    }
```

All articles I have searched discuss the command not firing and not firing when the data grid is scrolled. Any help or direction to an article would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: What are you doing in `ReasonChangedCommand` that you can't do in the setter of `SelectedReason` ?

Comment: The `ReasonChangedCommand` updates the `SelectedReason` for that datagrid row in a database

Answer (score 3):

After playing around with different event triggers, using `DropDownClosed` event resolves this issue.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. You saved my life :). Thanks !